# Is pointer-arithmetic in C aware of the data-type? or is pointer-arithmetic always in terms of bytes?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
long double* n = (long double*) malloc(256);
long double d = *(n + 3);
```

Did we just increment `n` by 3 bytes? Or did we increment by (3 times the number of bytes in a long double)?

Alternatively, is C smart enough to know that `n` points to an array of long doubles, or is C stupid, where it needs to be told exactly how many bytes to advance the pointer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character pointers and integer pointers (++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605689/character-pointers-and-integer-pointers)

Comment: Also, instead of `*(n + 3)` a C programmer would just write the shorter and nicer equivalent `n[3]`

Comment: In C pointer arithmetic works the same way as array indexing. The compiler knows that `n[1]` accesses the 10th... bytes (if `long double` is size 10). So `*(n + 1)` is the same.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is done in terms of objects, not bytes.  If `p` points to a 4-byte `int` object, then `p+1` points to the next 4-byte `int` object. If `p` points to an 8-byte `double`, then `p+1` points to the next 8-byte `double`.

Comment: `n` has type `long double *`  ,  not sure where "smart enough to know" comes into this